# Relink dropbox account on remote server

Tags: dropbox

I had a dropbox account on a remote linux server. Since I was having problems with dropbox (was getting python stacktraces) I unlinked my account (from the dropbox website) to relink it again, to see if that worked.

Unfortunately, now I cannot relink to my remote server. The first time I ran dropbox I got a link to use to connect my server to dropbox. This does not happen anymore. Even after uninstalling/reinstalling dropbox I still do not get a new link to reconnect my account, the dropbox status is just "Connecting" and nothing happens (which isn't strange, since it isn't allowed to connect to dropbox anymore).

[also sent to DB support, will post answer here if I get one]

Answer (score 0):

I was allowed to reconnect by just starting the dropbox daemon eventually, it just took (way too much) time.